# Deleted scene with Rose and 10th Doctor shortly after regeneration?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

2005 was a long time ago (I was 8) but there's a scene in my memory that I can't find on Netflix.

I remember a scene, immediately after the Doctor regenerates into his 10th form (excluding War Doctor), in which Rose basically asks stuff like "what have you done with the Doctor?". However, this scene appears to neither appear in "The Parting of the Ways" nor "The Christmas Invasion" on Netflix.

Is this scene real or did I just completely imagine the whole thing?

Comment: “2005 was a long time ago” — the Doctor gently mocks your quaint human conception of time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This scene formed a Children in Need special slotting just in between the events of *The Parting of the Ways* and *The Christmas Invasion*.

It's available in full on Youtube:

<sub>For me the most interesting part of this is to see the Tenth Doctor wearing the leather jacket of the Ninth - it's so weird not to see him in his own favoured trench coat!</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been bugging me for ages.

Comment: I *think* it's also on the DVDs

Comment: It's not included in the DVD box set I bought in the US in 2006. At least I didn't see it in there.