# When do the memories of all of the Doctor's past 13 faces' adventures come back after regenerating?

Tags: doctor-who

When the Doctor regenerates, he is wacky and has a hard time remembering stuff from his past - like this one time:

> DOCTOR: SS Marie Antoinette. Out of control repair droids cannibalising human beings. I know that this is familiar, but I just can't seem to place it.
>
> DOCTOR: Sister ship of the Madame De Pompadour. No, not getting it.

and also this time:

> DOCTOR: The Great Intelligence. Rings a bell. The Great Intelligence.

So it got me thinking: when do the memories of all the Doctor's past adventures as William Hartnell, Patrick Troughton, Jon Pertwee, Tom Baker, Peter Davison, Colin Baker, Sylvester McCoy, Paul McGann, John Hurt, Christopher Eccleston, David Tennant, Matt Smith, Peter Capaldi come back after regenerating?

Comment: It takes as long as is required by the plot. He normally seems fully functional in the second episode after regenerating (e.g. Series 2 Episode 1, Series 8 Episode 2), and sometimes even in the first (e.g. Series 5 Episode 1) depending on whether the showrunners want to make a thing out of him taking a while to recover his memory after regenerating.

Comment: the second one is from the snowmen Christmas special

Comment: In *The Snowmen* he wasn't newly regenerated, so it wasn't a case of his memory taking a while to come back after regeneration, but just standard forgetfulness which we all get sometimes.

Comment: why doesn't The Doctor  have a perfect memory and forget old adventures hes the doctor he should remember remember everything from all his past 13 faces advenutes

Comment: Do *you* have a perfect memory and remember every detail of everything that's ever happened to you? Nobody does, not even the Doctor.

Comment: why! hes lived for over 900 years he should remember  everything from all his past 13 faces advenutes

Comment: **Memories aren't perfect.** Imagine having lived for over 900 years, with constant excitement; that's a hell of a lot of experiences and adventures to remember. He's forgetful, just like everyone else.

Comment: so he dosent remember what his past faces looked liked like William Hartnell, Patrick Troughton, Jon Pertwee, Tom Baker, Peter Davison, Colin Baker, Sylvester McCoy, Paul McGann, John Hurt, Christopher Eccleston, David Tennant, Matt Smith

Comment: Yes he does. He remembers *most* things (like what his own face looked like), just not every single detail of everything he's ever done. That's how memory works, in the real world and in *Doctor Who*.

Comment: "there's no evidence of his memory being affected by regeneration" - I disagree. There's been a varying period of aberrant behavior as far back as Pertwee for sure, who lapsed into a near-coma for some time after regeneration. Baker behaved a bit strangely, ranting a bit, and popping off in the TARDIS almost immediately after regeneration to cause the events in *The Face of Evil*. Davison began making comments and talking like his past incarnations at the beginning of Castrovalva, eventually needing the Zero Room. Colin baker attacked Peri in a fit of paranoia. McCoy had complete amnesia for a

Answer (score 3):

### It takes as long as is required by the plot.

The Doctor often spends one episode immediately post-regeneration in some kind of confusion, but if kept up for too long this theme might bore the audience, so they drop it during or after the first post-regeneration episode. Or to put it a bit less cynically:

- In-universe, the Doctor takes an unknown but probably variable amount of time to recover from regeneration, usually **at most a day or two**.
- Out of universe, he spends **at most one episode** in post-regeneration confusion, and sometimes not even that.

Note however that in most cases **there's no evidence of his *memory* being affected by regeneration**. Your first quote comes from Series 8 Episode 1, *Deep Breath*; this is immediately after the Doctor's "clerical error" regeneration, and we can't expect moving on to a whole new regeneration cycle to work in the same way as just an ordinary regeneration does. Your second quote comes from the 2012 Christmas special *The Snowmen*, which doesn't take place soon after regeneration; there's no reason to think this is anything other than just normal forgetfulness which we all get sometimes.

So, bearing this in mind, in my answer below I'm going to focus mainly on his *physical* and *emotional* recovery from regeneration - how long it takes him to get back to full functionality in defeating evil aliens - without going into the issue of memory loss, which is usually a non-issue.

**Eccleston -> Tennant**
He regenerates in the TARDIS at the very end of Series 1 Episode 13, *The Parting of the Ways*. After that, it's only a matter of minutes until he and Rose return to the Powell estate; this scene [was included in](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117904/deleted-scene-with-rose-and-10th-doctor-shortly-after-regeneration/117906#117906) a Children in Need special which leads into the 2005 Christmas special *The Christmas Invasion*. In that episode, he takes **less than two days** to recover physically from regeneration. It's not clear whether he has any memory problems at the end of this episode, but he seems to be back to full functionality in Series 2 Episode 1, *New Earth*, which takes place an unknown amount of time later.

**Tennant -> Smith**
This time the Doctor recovers quickly, and doesn't appear to be suffering from post-regeneration trauma or confusion for most of his first episode as Matt Smith (Series 5 Episode 1, *The Eleventh Hour*). At most, any problems last on the scale of **hours** rather than days.

**Smith -> Capaldi**
This is the strange one, the "clerical error" as the Doctor once put it himself. He wasn't supposed to get any more regenerations, but his [regeneration 'batteries' were recharged](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123999/how-does-the-12th-doctor-remember-all-the-adventures-of-his-first-regeneration-c/124057#124057) at the last moment. This probably explains his post-regeneration confusion throughout most of Series 8 Episode 1, *Deep Breath*. We've no idea how much time elapsed between *The Time of the Doctor* and *Deep Breath* (evidently enough to go back in time and pick up a dinosaur before jumping forwards to Victorian London), but assuming it was at most a few hours, we again get a figure of **at most a couple of days** before apparent full recovery by the end of *Deep Breath*.

Comment: i made comments hours ago you forgot to answer called   
what every single detail just curious and well the doctor has a diary and a big book called 900 years diary it has all of his life ever tying hes ever done

Comment: how is there  no evidence of his memory being affected by regeneration

Comment: @AndrewCasali 1) I don't know what "what every single detail just curious" means. 2) Yes, he has a diary. That doesn't mean he knows where to find every little event of his life in there. Imagine you had a massive encyclopedia covering 900 years of adventures; would you immediately be able to find "the Great Intelligence" somewhere in it? Especially if you didn't actually have the encyclopedia to hand. 3) Well, what evidence is there of his memory being affected by regeneration (other than the "clerical error" Capaldi regeneration)? If you find some evidence, then I retract my statement.

Comment: what most things does he remember  all of his past adventures his past 13 faces or people Friends or monsters he met before

Comment: @AndrewCasali Obviously he remembers most things in his life, just like all of us. Even more obviously, I can't give you a list of everything he remembers. See also [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124048/31394).

Comment: you could to give me a list im just asking you these questions you a good expert on memories on doctor who because memories on doctor who is confusing for me

Comment: @AndrewCasali It's impossible to make a list of everything somebody remembers. (Could *you* make a list of every single event you remember from *your* past?) Particularly impossible when that somebody is a fictional character and we don't know they remember something until they show us that they do. The best list I've got is the one I just linked you to.

Comment: what about when he remembered the diner with amy and roroy  river the cyber planner saying 9th 10th catchphrase he meet the forest of cheem him remembering the events of the 50th Evan though the time streams out of sync 10th remembering sarah jane him remembbering the master when he was missy

Comment: @AndrewCasali Now I've no idea what you're talking about. However, I've [copied these comments to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38080/discussion-between-rand-althor-and-andrew-casali), so we can continue the discussion there. And I'll delete all the comments here, since they're now copied into chat.

Comment: When the Doctor was aboard the SS Marie Antoinette, it was *over a thousand years* since he had been on the Madame de Pompadour. And when he faced the Great Intelligence with (a) Clara, it was at least a few centuries since he'd last fought it, and it looked much different back then.